# QGraphicsView does not show anything in Qt 5.0

Tags: qt

I am new to Qt 5.0 and I am trying to use a QGraphicsView called "missionView" of size 700x400 inside a QWidget to show a rectangle. However, nothing shows up inside the graphics view on running the application. Here is the constructor of the QWidget "MainView" where I am doing everything

```
MainView::MainView(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainView)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
QGraphicsScene scene(0, 0, 500, 500);
QGraphicsRectItem* myrect = scene.addRect(QRectF(0,0,15,5),QPen(), QBrush());


ui->missionView->setScene(&scene);

ui->missionView->setVisible(true);
ui->missionView->show();
ui->missionView->update();
printf("QGraphicsScene scene's items: %d\n",scene.items().size());
    for (int i = 0; i < scene.items().size(); i++) {
        printf("%d\n",scene.items().at(i));
    }


}
```

The last print statement does show that one item has been added but still nothing gets shown. I have tried an approach similar to [this](http://www.qtforum.org/article/25299/using-qgraphicsscene-and-qgraphicsview.html) but this too dosent work. Can anyone please explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the scene object on the stack.
Thus the scene will be destroyed right away at the end of the constructor and thus nothing will be shown.
Create the scene on the heap and/or make it a class member and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Frank for explaining. I added it to the class and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was looking at the Qt help documentation and their examples are allocating the Scene on the stack so its very confusing. Switching to a heap allocated scene did the trick.